# c# wpf session storing and retrieving

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

I have a login validation where the users will enter their identity card number. In the database, the identity card number is linked to several information.
What I want to do is to create a session in the login page where the identity card number will be stored in a string or object and it can be retrieved in another page to call out for the information in the database. However, I have been looking around for solutions but unable to find any. Would be great is anyone can help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have many possibilities;

```
Application.Current.Properties["ID"] = id; //id is the value you got from the database.
```

to use it, in the page you want just type

```
int id = int.Parse(Application.Current.Properties["ID"].ToString());
```

to remove it

```
Application.Current.Properties.Remove("ID");
```

The second approach would be creating static variable

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int ID = 0;
}
```

and to access it just call `MyClass.ID`